# Show selected items value/text using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a step by step order for my personal service.

I want to grab the selected items and display the unique `.name` and `.price` in another part of the page.

To explain my HTML, the selectable content is `<li class="service">` and these items have a `<span class="name"> example service </span>` and a `<span class="price"> $9.99 </span>` which is the price of this unique service. Once a service has been selected, it will look like `<li class="service selected">` and the next services for this service will be displayed underneath, like step by step is supposed to work.

My goal is once one `<li class="service">` has the class `.selected` I want to display the `<span class="name">` and `<span class="price">` in a list which is a list where the customer has control over the price and his selected services. If it's not selected it will not show in "Your order"

This is some of my code:

```
var selected = $('.selected');
var name = $('.name'); // grab the <span id="name">
var price = $('.price'); // grab the <span id="price">

$(".service").click(function() { 
   $( "li.order > span.service_name" ).html( name ).show();
   $( "li.order > span.service_price" ).html( price ).show();
});
```

This is close to what I want. At least something changed once I clicked on a service.

Code is in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/superladremi/vx9ubra7/1/) for you to see, click on any of the services to see the code go to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's quite a lot of problems with your code, but I figured this is the beginning of what you want to do: https://jsfiddle.net/vx9ubra7/3/

There are quite a lot of issues here, but there are 2 biggest issues:

1. Like any other things in programming, do **NOT** give 2 different things the same `id`. Ever.
2. To get an element by its id, use the `#` sign (`$("#id")`), to get elements by their class, use the `.` sign (`$(".class")`).

Comment: Thanks so much for taking your time to improve the code I wrote and for pointing out my mistakes. Your JSFiddle update is very close to what I want.